# How do I disable scrolling in Urxvt?

Tags: tmux, rxvt

Is it possible to disable scrolling in urxvt when we use with `tmux`? The problem I have is that `tmux` `clear-history` command won't clear the urxvt scroll buffer (`Shift+Page Up`), hence we always have history in the console. The only other way isto detach Tmux and `reset` the Terminal to clear this content. Would it be possible to make `urxvt` to have no scroll so that I can handle everything in `tmux` which is more logical when you use `tmux`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the following in `~/.Xdefaults` to force Urxvt to not keep any history:

```
URxvt*saveLines:0
```

This will render `Shift + PgUp` as a no-op, even in Tmux.

Comment: Nice, this is the setting I am looking for. Just curious, are you aware of a command line arguement for this? I need this only when I plan to use tmux in urxvt usually. All other scenarios saveLines is usually fine.

Comment: @Nishant, sure. Resources can be used as arguments to `urxvt` like this: `urxvt --saveLines 0`.

Comment: @Nishant, in this case there is even an option available: `urxvt -sl 0`. Just have a look into `man urxvt`.